# Icon linked to wrong command

Tags: command-line, icons, lxterminal

Terminal emulator in my pc  wasn't set . So, I wasn't able to open current folder in terminal from GUI options. It asked me to set terminal emulator

[image]

While setting up emulator by mistake I entered "lx-terminal" instead of "lxterminal" .

Now I can't access lxterminal by clicking on icon .
It shows me

Failed to execute child process “lx-terminal” (No such file or directory)
error

I tried sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator , but still can't access lxterminal from clicking lxterminal icon

PS: I can access lxterminal from typing lxterminal on xterm and left click on desktop -> than open terminal. But not from icon itself!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is it?

Comment: @David I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.6 with LXDE as DE

Answer (score 0):

You need to change settings here:
PCManFM -> Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced Tab

More details you can see by this link: https://pc.odesa.in/2022/12/15/failed-to-execute-child-process-lx-terminal-no-such-file-or-directory-error/